# Prevent other fields in loop from changing with state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What's the best way to accomplish something like this. I have a credit note that I wish to edit the unit price. I'll pull in the invoice details then the user can edit/change the unit price. When I do this, all fields are changing. Somehow I need to put this in its own state? I have no idea how.

**Parent Component using React.createClass:**

```
line_items = [
  {
    id: 1,
    unit_amount: "250.00",
    ...
  },
  {
    ...,
    unit_amount: "20.00",
    ...
  }
]

//render
<LineItems items={this.props.line_items} />
```

**Child Component using React.createClass:**

```
getInitialState(){
  return{
    creditedValues: []
  }
},

_valueChange(e){
  this.setState({creditedValues: this.state.creditedValues.concat([e.target.value])})
},

render(){
  var items = this.props.items;
  if (items.length !== 0) {
    var lineItems = items.map(function(l){
      return(
        <tr key={l.id}>
          <td data-label="Payment">{l.description}</td>
          <td className="credit-note-qty" data-label="Issue Date">{l.quantity}</td>
          <td className="credit-note-up" data-label="Amount">{l.unit_amount}</td>
          <td className="credit-note-amt" data-label="Period">
            <input type="number" value={this.state.newValue} onChange={this._valueChange} />
          </td>
        </tr>
      )
    }.bind(this));
  };

  return(<tbody>{lineItems}</tbody>)
}
```

Before I changed to `concat`, when I change a value, all values change at the same time. How to prevent this?

**Edit:**

I have updated the `_valueChange` with:

```
_valueChange(i, e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var obj = this.props.creditNote.line_items;
  var num = obj.find(p => i === p.id);
  num.unit_amount = e.target.value;
  this.setState({creditedValues : num});
}
```

**Input now changes to:**

```
<input type="number" value={this.state.newValue} onChange={this._valueChange.bind(this, l.id)} />
```

Now I have exactly what I want but there is a but. If the user update another input field, it replace the entire state. True, as the code I have replaces the entire state. If the user update two or more fields, how to keep the new objects?